# Tasker Profile Help

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, tasker

I have been playing around with Tasker lately and had a good idea that I would like to implement but I am new to Tasker and so I can only create simple profiles.

My idea, for myself, is that my phone remains without some sort of password or pin, until someone places their hand above the proximity sensor on my Galaxy S4. Then, the phone requires a password/pin. Otherwise, it remains without one.

How would I go about doing such a thing? I played around with the proximity sensor but I set the context for the proximity sensor as a "State" and I'm not sure how to set something that would implement the proximity sensor. Also, I would like to know if I can set it to lock the phone when someone's hand is within a certain distance.

Comment: Is there anyone that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the proximity sensor gives 1 if it's covered, 0 if not. So you just want to use the state to detect it, then run a task for activating the password.